# AWS API Gateway caches POST data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I turned on the cache to cache GET requests but it also applies to POST, since post has no query string it currently caches the POST once and sticks with it no matter the POST body.

Is there a way to turn this off for the POST method or tell the cache that the post body has the key to cache it?

Answer (score 8):

I would start by reading [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html) on this feature carefully.

You can enable caching [at the stage level](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html#enable-api-gateway-caching), and you can override cache settings [at the method level](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html#override-api-gateway-stage-cache-for-method-cache). You can also specify headers, URL paths and query strings [to be used as the cache key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html#enable-api-gateway-cache-keys).

It's not clear what you have done at this point but you should be able to do one of the following to achieve your goals:

1. Enable caching at the stage level, and disable at the method level for the POST method.
2. Disable caching at the stage level, and enable caching at the method level for the GET method.

Answer (score 3):

They may have fixed this since you posted it, but right there in the documentation, it says clearly:

> **Important**
>
> Only GET methods can be cached.

If this is still happening, it's a bug - but it shouldn't be. I'm not seeing it.

D

Comment: well, it's been 2 years, very likely :D - maybe I should delete this question since it's kinda useless now.

Answer (score 0):

Just to not lead people to a wrong direction, now it's possible to configure which HTTP verb you want to cache.

[From the doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html) :

> When you enable caching for a stage, only GET methods have caching
>   enabled by default. This helps to ensure the safety and availability
>   of your API. You can enable caching for other methods by overriding
>   method settings.